# How to map 2D display coordinate to 3D OpenGL space

Tags: android, c, opengl-es, 3d, coordinate-transformation

I am working on a 3D game that is ported on Android and I want to work with touch events in 3D course of a game. I need point in 3D space, right on near clipping plane, but all I can get is a 2D coordinates from an Android display. So, is there any way to map these (x, y) coordinates to (x, y, z) coordinates in 3D space?

## EDIT

Well, I am working on a racing game, and I want to insert some items on a course, depending on where I click. I have this function:

```
void racing_mouse_cb(int button, int state, int x, int y) { //parameters (x,y) are coords of a display
    set_ill_fish(get_player_data( local_player())->view);
}
```

but for now I am inserting items in front of a player at some distance:

```
void set_ill_fish(view_t view) {
    item_locs[num_items].ray.pt.x = view.plyr_pos.x;
    item_locs[num_items].ray.pt.z = view.plyr_pos.z - 5;
    item_locs[num_items].ray.pt.y = find_y_coord(view.plyr_pos.x,
            view.plyr_pos.z - 5) + 0.2;
    item_locs[num_items].ray.vec = make_vector(0, 1, 0);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

, but how to translate this to display surface, I am clueless.

Comment: What have you tried allready? Post that code then we can have a look where we can help you.

Comment: send a ray into the Z-pane on the x-y-touch and see, what object you hit.

Comment: To translate a point from 2D screen to 3D world, you can use `gluUnproject`, see [http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/using_gluunproject/16013/](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/using_gluunproject/16013/)

Comment: Wikibooks has an article on this stuff http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Object_selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remap 2D display coordinates `(display_x, display_y)` to 3D object coordinates `(x,y,z)` you need to know

1. the depth `display_z` of the pixel at `(display_x, display_y)`
2. the transformation `T` that transforms clip space coordinates `(clip_x, clip_y, clip_z)` to display coordinates
3. the transformation `M` that transforms object coordinates to clip space coordinates (usually combines a camera and a perspective)

The display coordinates are computed as follows

```
M.transform(x, y, z, 1) --> (clip_x, clip_y, clip_z, clip_w)

T.transform(clip_x / clip_w, clip_y / clip_w, clip_z / clip_w) --> (display_x, display_y, display_z)
```

`M.transform` is an invertible matrix multiplication and `T.transform` is any invertible transformation.

You can recover `(x,y,z)` from `(display_x, display_y, display_z)` as follows

```
T.inverse_transform(display_x, display_y, display_z) --> (a, b, c)

M.inverse_transform(a, b, c, 1) --> (X, Y, Z, W)

(X/W, Y/W, Z/W) --> (x, y, z)
```

The following gives intuition on why the above computation leads to the right solution

```
T.inverse_transform(display_x, display_y, display_z) --> (clip_x / clip_w, clip_y / clip_w, clip_z / clip_w)

(clip_x / clip_w, clip_y / clip_w, clip_z / clip_w, clip_w / clip_w) == (clip_x, clip_y, clip_z, clip_w) / clip_w

M.inverse_transform((clip_x, clip_y, clip_z, clip_w) / clip_w) == M.inverse_transform(clip_x, clip_y, clip_z, clip_w) / clip_w

M.inverse_transform(clip_x, clip_y, clip_z, clip_w) / clip_w --> (x, y, z, 1) / clip_w

(x, y, z, 1) / clip_w == (x / clip_w, y / clip_w, z / clip_w, 1 / clip_w)

(x / clip_w, y / clip_w, z / clip_w, 1 / clip_w) == (X, Y, Z, W)
```

The above used the following matrix (`M`) vector (`v`) scalar (`a == 1 / clip_w`) property:

```
M * (a * v) == a * (M * v)
```