# OpenGL 1.1 scene coordinates to screen coordinates

Tags: opengl, opengl-1.x

I know OpenGL 1.x is more than only outdated but due to the required target hardware which lacks better OpenGL drivers, I'm bound to this kind of legacy code. Or in other words: people pay for support of this old crap and who pays is the boss...

My problem: Before sending my objects coordinates, I set some transformation with functions glLoadIdentity(), glTranslatef(), glScaled(), glRotatef() to change the view to my objects by translating/zooming/rotating.

These parameters can be changed by the user to get a different view to the scene (by dragging the mouse on the related window).

My problem: how can I convert between the scene-coordinates (based on the transformation done by the functions described above) and the draw-canvas coordinates (means position of the mouse on the window that displays the scene)?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360952/how-to-map-2d-display-coordinate-to-3d-opengl-space

Comment: @codetiger: No, this "Duplicate" does not deal with OpenGL 1.1

Comment: The problem is not related to OpenGL ES 1.1 specific. calculating 3d position from screen coordinates is a common problem in OpenGL. You can use the same implementation for both. You just have to multiply the position with view matrix with the distance of object.

Comment: @codetiger: the problem IS OpenGL 1.1 specific because I do not have access to any other (OpenGL) functions, therefore all the other threads out there do not fit to my question!

Comment: @codetiger: may be you better read my posting, there is no view matrix I could use...

Comment: For OpenGL ES 2.0 we construct & pass the view matrix but in ES1.1 you construct the matrix only for this purpose. You don't have to send the matrix to OpenGL ES for setting up.

Comment: @codetiger: once again, read my posting! I'm not talking about OpenGL ES but about OpenGL!

Comment: Please read this answer, this is exactly what I was trying to explain. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51802/selecting-and-moving-object-in-opengl-gameplay3d-engine

Comment: @Elmi: "*once again, read my posting! I'm not talking about OpenGL ES but about OpenGL!*" Well, your "posting" was tagged OpenGL ES. And those functions exist in ES 1.1 just like desktop GL 1.1. So the misconception is your fault. And codetiger's point still remains: the *math* to do it is the same regardless of the OpenGL version. The only difference is that OpenGL is storing the matrix data rather than yourself. So the only thing you have to do differently is fetch the matrix data via OpenGL commands.